# I don't konw what is wrong with my result set in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am new in java programing and I'm trying to understand why I'm having the error below:
I have almost spent 6 hours and no luck, I have rebooted mysql server and my PC also the ip and port 
are Ok. What's wrong with mt 'ResultSet'? Can some one help me with this please.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    char[] tempPass = password.getPassword();
                    typedPassword = new String(tempPass);

                    if (!username.getText().equals("") && !typedPassword.equals("")) {

                        String sql = "SELECT id, username, password, admin FROM users where username=? and password=?";
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                            statement.setString(1, username.getText().toString());
                            statement.setString(2, typedPassword);

                            ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();                   
                            String admin = set.getString("admin");
                            preferences.put("user_id", set.getString("id"));

                            int count = 0;
                            while (set.next()) {
                                count++;
                            }

                            if (count == 1) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, "Login success");

                                if (chckbxRememberMe.isSelected()) {
                                    DoLogin log = new DoLogin();
                                    log.execute();
                                } else {
                                    DoDelete delete = new DoDelete();
                                    delete.execute();
                                }
                                if(admin.equals("1")){
                                    Login.this.hide();
                                    Admin frMain = new Admin();
                                    frMain.setVisible(true);
                                    frMain.show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    Login.this.hide();
                                    Customer frMain = new Customer();
                                    frMain.setVisible(true);
                                    frMain.show();
                                }

                            } else if (count > 1) {
                                System.out.println("Duplicate");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("not Exists");
                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "Fields can not be empty");
                    } 
                }

            });
```

Here is the Error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:484)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:834)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:852)
            at msm.Login$3.actionPerformed(Login.java:175)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You cannot call `String admin = set.getString("admin");` before you move the cursor forward. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next() * A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row;*

Comment: Have you tried to research what that exception is trying to tell you?

Comment: "Before start of result set" and checking the [javadoc of ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html): "A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between these two lines:

> ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
>   String admin = set.getString("admin");

You need to add `set.next()` to actually read a line from result set. Every time you run `set.next()` it moves to the next line. For example:

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();                   
while (set.next()) {
  String admin = set.getString("admin");
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the `set.getString("admin");` from the following lines.

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
String admin = set.getString("admin");
```

After executing the query, you need to perform a `set.next()` before accessing the admin info, because your cursor is not moving forward otherwise (the cursor is the `ResultSet`)

Way of fixing it:

```
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
if (set.next()) {
   String admin = set.getString("admin");   
   // .. rest of your code
}
```